# Three.js scene gets hanged and becomes slow

Tags: javascript, three.js

The threejs scene consists of sphere and plane geometry, The sphere is textured with image and plane geometry
is textured with 2d text, and plane geometry is attached with click event, When I click on plane geometry 
with the mouse I need to remove the previous sphere and plane geometry and load new sphere with new textured 
image and new plane geometry which is happening, but the previous sphere and plane geometry are still remaining in memory and i need
to remove those objects, i tried using "dispose" method but that didn't help me may be i am making some mistake
to implement the dispose method,because of this the scene gets hanged, can someone please help me how to solve 
this problem. I have added part of my code which might give an idea regarding the problem.[https://jsfiddle.net/v1ayw803/](https://jsfiddle.net/lakers1234/v1ayw803/)

```
var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20, 0, -6.283, 1, 1);
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(response.ImagePath);
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial);
//texture.needsUpdate = true;

scene.add(sphere);
var objects = [];
var objects_sphere = [];
objects_sphere.push(sphere);

for(var i=0; i<spriteResponse.length; i++)
            {

                var cardinal = {ID: parseInt(spriteResponse[i].ID), lat: parseFloat(spriteResponse[i].lat), lon: parseFloat(spriteResponse[i].lng), name: spriteResponse[i].name};
                //var sprite =  new labelBox(cardinal, radius, root);
                //sprite.update();  was previously commented        
                //spritearray.push(sprite);

                var phi = Math.log( Math.tan( cardinal.lat*(Math.PI/180) / 2 + Math.PI / 4 ) / Math.tan( click_marker.getPosition().lat()* (Math.PI/180) / 2 + Math.PI / 4) );
                var delta_lon = Math.abs( click_marker.getPosition().lng() - cardinal.lon )*Math.PI/180;
                var bearing = Math.atan2( delta_lon ,  phi ) ;
                var Z_value = Math.cos(bearing)*(radius*0.75);
                var X_value = Math.sin(bearing)*(radius*0.75);

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                metrics = null,
                textHeight = 32,
                textWidth = 0,
            //  actualFontSize = 2;
                context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
                metrics = context.measureText(cardinal.name);
                var textWidth = metrics.width;
                //var textHeight = metrics.height;
                canvas.width = textWidth;
                canvas.height = textHeight;
                context.font = "normal " + textHeight + "px Arial";
                context.textAlign = "center";
                context.textBaseline = "middle";
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(0, 0, textWidth, textHeight);
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fill();

                context.fillStyle = "black";
                context.fillText(cardinal.name, textWidth / 2, textHeight / 2);


                texture_plane = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
                var GPU_Value = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
                texture_plane.anisotropy = GPU_Value;
                texture_plane.needsUpdate = true;



                //var spriteAlignment = new THREE.Vector2(0,0) ;
                material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff,side: THREE.DoubleSide ,map : texture_plane} );
                material.needsUpdate = true;
                //material.transparent=true;
                geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.3, 0.2);
                plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                plane.database_id = cardinal.ID;
                plane.LabelText   = cardinal.name;


                //plane.scale.set( 0.3, 0.3,1 );
                plane.scale.set( textWidth/165, textHeight/70, 1 );
                plane.position.set(X_value,0,Z_value);
                plane.coordinates = { X: X_value, Z: Z_value};
                plane.lat_lon = { LAT: cardinal.lat, LON: cardinal.lon};
                plane.textWidth = textWidth;
                plane.textHeight = textHeight;
                objects.push( plane );
                scene.add(plane);
                plane.userData = { keepMe: true };
                //objects.push( plane );
                //plane.id = cardinal.ID;
                //var direction = camera.getWorldDirection();
                camera.updateMatrixWorld();
                var vector = camera.position.clone();
                vector.applyMatrix3( camera.matrixWorld );
                plane.lookAt(vector);



                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );


            }
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
            {

                //clearScene();
                event.preventDefault();

                var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );               
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );                 

                var matched_marker = null;
                if(intersects.length != 0)
                {   
                    for ( var i = 0;  intersects.length > 0 && i < intersects.length; i++)
                    {
                        var x_id = intersects[0].object.database_id;                        
                            for( var j = 0; markers.length > 0 && j < markers.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(x_id == markers[j].ID)
                            {
                                matched_marker = markers[j];
                                break;
                            }                               
                        }
                        if(matched_marker != null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }       
                    }

                     // loadScene();
                    clean_data();
                    google.maps.event.trigger( matched_marker, 'click' );


                }

        }
   function clean_data()
        {
            for(var k=0;k<objects_sphere.length;k++)
            {
                scene.remove( objects_sphere[k] );
                objects_sphere[k].geometry.dispose();
                objects_sphere[k].material.map.dispose();
                objects_sphere[k].material.dispose();



            }

            for (var j=0; j<objects.length; j++)
            {
                scene.remove( objects[j] );
                objects[j].geometry.dispose();
                objects[j].material.map.dispose();
                objects[j].material.dispose();

            //  objects[j].material.needsUpdate = true;




            }

            /*spheregeometry.dispose();
            spherematerial.dispose();
            texture.dispose();
            scene.remove( sphere );*/
        } `
```

Comment: your js fiddle isn't working

Comment: I don't see a renderer.render() call, are you making sure to rerender the scene after removing your objects?

Comment: @Brandon.Blanchard i added animationLoop function and called that function in clean_data function but nothing changed.

Comment: @lakers1234 Maybe I missed it, but I don't see where you call clean_data();

Comment: @pprchsvr i have called clean_data(); @ function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're never rerendering the scene in either the example code or the jsFiddle. If you remove your object from the scene and the objects remain, it's likely that you've not rendered the scene again. Try adding a render loop.

```
animationLoop () {
    myrenderer.render(myScene, myCamera)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop)
}
```